# SharePoint Query Rule Guidance

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, sharepoint-search, promoted-links

Need some guidance on setting up a query rule to display a page as a promoted result. I have a web page containing multiple links pointing to my corporate policies (email, alcohol/drugs use, anti-harassment, data and information etc. ).

I would like this page to be displayed as a promoted result not only when people search for a policy, corporate policy, email policy, but also for recording policy etc. (synonyms included). I did setup a promoted result for exact terms when searched, but not sure of alternate keyword search (like recording policy) too to return the promoted result.

Should I include all keywords in the exact search terms or a better way out?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways for you to look at this. For example, should you create a single promoted result, or multiple, pointing to the same resource, based on different triggers? The key is that you can report on the usage of your Query Rules and see which are firing. Recently we created a promoted result and did not want to "harass" our users so we added a link that says "I see this too often". After about 25 days folks started clicking the links, so we took the feedback and adjusted the rule.

You can also use regex to detect the word in proximity to "policy" and actually change the query to pull the policies (rather than use the promoted result), but that would be a different user experience.

Comment: Agreed. But in my case, there are multiple policy links already listed on the web page. Would you recommend to put synonyms for each policy in the same query rule and create a promoted result to that web page or create multiple query rules with synonyms for each policy pointing to the same policy web page? Can you point me to an article using regex with query change

Comment: It all depends on what you want to see in your reports. Do you care how the rule is getting triggered? If so, go more granular, if not then use one rule. Regex can be used on-prem for the query match construction. I dabble in regex but am by no means an expert.